# Remove white space from pre/code tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using prism.js to highlight code.This is the code that i used to make a simple output.The problem is that there are unwanted white spaces on top and bottom. [Live example](http://css-shapes.xyz/transparent-cut-out-edge)

```
<pre>
  <code class="language-css">
    &lt;div class="test_class"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

[image: white space]

Is there a way to remove the unwanted spaces(the part shown in the red part) using css or jquery ?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/0.0.1/prism.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/0.0.1/prism.min.css" type="text/css">
<pre>
 <code class="language-css">
.some_code{


}
     </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: You mean to hide scrollbars?

Comment: No @VisioN i mean the padding like area seen on top and bottom

Comment: Need better example markup than what you've supplied cause this could be one of several things.

Comment: Maybe adding `style="white-space: normal"` or `style="white-space: nowrap"` to the `pre` and to the `code`?

Comment: Can you explain better @Rob i mean how do you want me to edit it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the line-breaks inside of the `<code>` block is being taken into account. I guess you will have to trim your code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/0.0.1/prism.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/0.0.1/prism.min.css" type="text/css">
<pre>
<code class="language-css">.some_code{


}</code></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks Nico this does solve it but there is till white space on the bottom

Comment: Same problem as on the top. Updated the code snipped and removed unnecessary line breaks.

Comment: You need to do corresponding trimming at the bottom too. Also between `pre` and `code` tags, to remove spaces entirely. I'll do the same for my blog posts, as I spotted this issue recently! Thanks

Comment: Thanks @robjez that remove all the white spaces

Answer (score 3):

Try this: Its will remove all margin & padding from this.

```
<pre>
<code class="language-css">.some_code{


}
</code>
</pre>
```

CSS:

```
pre, code {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Can you refine your CSS code. Which part of (div, any class) you want to update with padding?

Answer (score 3):

Prism.js has a few unfriendly quirks. I updated to this new behaviour today and could not possibly fix all of my blog posts manually.

Just run this code on page load to trim leading/trailing whitespace from all code blocks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("code[class^='language-']").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().trim());
  });

  Prism.highlightAll();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but if you run the code with my snippet, it won't work well as expected

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{margin:0 ; padding:0;}
pre{margin:0!important ; padding:0!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/0.0.1/prism.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/0.0.1/prism.min.css" type="text/css">
<pre>
  <code class="language-css">
    &lt;div class="test_class"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```